# Shared weight matrices between dense layers in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to reimplement this tensorflow code into keras, I have noted other tickets submitted here that do not share the sentiment I am trying to recreate. The goal is to share a weight matrix across multiple dense layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# define input and weight matrices
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32)
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=.1, shape=[4, 12]), 
                 dtype=tf.float32)
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(stddev=.1, shape=[12, 2]), 
                 dtype=tf.float32)
# neural network
hidden_1 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, w1))
projection = tf.matmul(hidden_1, w2)
hidden_2 = tf.nn.tanh(projection)
hidden_3 = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(hidden_2, tf.transpose(w2)))
y = tf.matmul(hidden_3, tf.transpose(w1))
# loss function and optimizer
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum((x - y) * (x - y), 1))
optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

The issue is reimplementing these weight layers in keras as the transpose of original layers. I am currently implementing my own network using keras functional API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by defining your two dense layers:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda
import keras.backend as K

dense1 = Dense(12, use_bias=False, activation='tanh')
dense2 = Dense(2, use_bias=False, activation='tanh')
```

You can then access the weights from your layers with for example `dense1.weights[0]`. You can wrap this in a lambda layer that also transposes your weights:

```
h3 = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(x, K.transpose(dense2.weights[0])))(h2)
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it, this is what I was looking for! Is there a way to initialize a dense layer weights with another dense layer?

Comment: You can just reuse the dense layer on multiple inputs. Otherwise, if you want two separate layers that update their weights separately, you can use set_weights. For example: dense2.set_weights(dense1.weights)

Comment: Thanks again, you have been a great help.